# How to get media link in sitecore rss feed

Tags: c#, sitecore8

I am setting a feed for media items in sitecore and followed the setup guide and everything works ok. However, the link tag in the feed generates the absolute path to the media item in the content tree, something like this

[image]

What we want is the url to the image on the server like http://ecms-site1.intlsos.com/-/media/corporate/..../incident-occurs.mp3

I inherited from PublicFeed class to add extra property in the rss feed, but need help changing the behaviour of the link property to return the media url.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

For media items you should use Sitecore MediaManager, not LinkManager as for ordinary pages, and specify MediaUrlOptions to control absolute and relative URLs for your media assets.
The below code defines an extension for a Sitecore media item to generate an absolute URL for it:

```
using Sitecore.Resources.Media;

public static string AbsoluteMediaItemUrl(this Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem item)
            {
                MediaUrlOptions mediaUrlOptions = new MediaUrlOptions
                {
                    AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true,
                    AbsolutePath = true
                };
                return MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(item, mediaUrlOptions);
            }
```

In order to override the standard RSS feed functionality in Sitecore you have to create your custom class inherited from *Sitecore.Syndication.PublicFeed* and override *SyndicationItem RenderItem(Item item)* method. Next you require to map your newly created class to your RSS Feed Item in Sitecore to specify what custom class you want to reference to instead of the standard PublicFeed one.

Comment: Hi, i have tried that and i get the correct media item url, however i cannot seem to override the out-of-box rss feed's link node which should return me back the correct url

Comment: You certainly can. Please see above about how to override the standard _RenderItem()_ in _PublicFeed_.